# Swift3: AFNetworking Issues converting failure Block from Swift2 to Swift3

Tags: swift3, afnetworking, swift2

I am converting my Swift2 code to Swift3.

Code in Swift2

```html
manager.post(url, parameters: dict,
      success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?, responseObject: Any?) in
          self.removeActivityIndicator()                    
          
          if let jsonDict = self.parseJSON(responseObject) {
              callback(jsonDict)
          }
      },
      failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
          self.removeActivityIndicator()
          
          print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
          var dict = error.userInfo
          dict["error"] = error.localizedDescription
          if let jsonDict = dict as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
              callback(jsonDict)
          }
      }
  )
```

In Failure section I got the following error message,

```
Cannot convert value of type '(AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> ()' to expected argument type '((AFHTTPRequestOperation?, Error?) -> Void)!'
```

When I convert `failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!)` to `failure: { (operation, error)`

I got and error on line

```
var dict = error.userInfo
```

as 'Value of type Error has no member UserInfo'

Comment: First: Did you update AFNetworking? Any reason why you don't prefer Alamofire (same family of frameworks by group authors) which is more Swift? Did you try to let the autocompletion do its job? The signature in Swift 3 for that block has changed that's what the error is saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

. .  Use Alamofire as Larme advised or explore some other service. Alamofire is same as AFNetworking and very flexible. You will integrate with a minor change in your code. AFNetworking is not much supported by Swift3,4.